# Follow-up to "How do I execute a program or call a system command?"

Tags: python, shell, terminal, subprocess, command

I have a related question to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-do-i-execute-a-program-or-call-a-system-command). The command that I'd like to execute is this one:

```bash
program test.in > test.out
```

where `program` takes as input `test.in` and outputs `test.out`. In python, I do

```
import subprocess


subprocess.Popen([program] + ['test.in > test.out'])
```

yet I get the error

```
Cannot open file 'test.in > test.out' for reading.
```

I've also tried

```
subprocess.Popen([program] + 'test.in > test.out'.split())
```

yet this results in the error

```
Cannot open file `>` for reading.
```

How do I need to modify my script without using `shell=True`, which would pose a security threat? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, without changing command:

```
import subprocess

cmd = "program test.in > test.out"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Edited:
As answer to a comment:

```
with open('test.out', 'w') as outfile:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(['program', 'test.in'], stdout=outfile)
```

This code splits the command "program test.in > test.out" into the list ['program', 'test.in']. It also redirects the output to a file named test.out using the stdout parameter.

Comment: > How do I need to modify my script without using `shell=True`, which would pose a security threat?

Answer (score -1):

If the program takes them in as arguments, then you should just follow the normal syntax for Popen like this:

```
subprocess.Popen(['program', 'test.in', '>', 'test.out'])
```

Is there a reason you're not following this syntax?

Comment: Yes, there's a reason why I'm not following your suggestion. When I do as you suggested, I get the error `Cannot open file '>' for reading.`

This is a bit of a pity, since `program` seems to interpret `>` as a file instead of an assignment operator to a file...